# ActiveXを使わずにwebブラウザ上でクライアントのexeを実行する方法

Tags: windows, browser

クライアントPCのexeファイル，例えば`C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe`をブラウザ上から実行する方法を探しています．ネットで検索するとActiveXを使った方法が多く紹介されていましたが、ActiveXはEdgeで対応していないので、ActiveXを使わない方法を探しています．

単純に

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="file:///C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe">電卓</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

としてもうまくいきません．

クライアントのexeを起動させるのはセキュリティ上問題があるのは承知の上で質問しています．
何か簡単な方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 8):

セキュリティ上、任意のEXEを起動させる仕組みは用意されていません。
別の方法として、対象PCに[URIがレジストリ登録](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)されていれば、登録内容に従ってEXEを起動することができます。

例えば

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\note
URL Protocol = ""
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\note\shell\open\command
(Default) = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

とレジストリ登録がしてあれば

```
<a href="note:">notepad</a>
```

で起動します。

Comment: レジストリに登録することで上手くいきました．ちなみにEXEを起動させる際に、管理者権限で起動させることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: それはWebブラウザーとは無関係で[Application Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375635.aspx)に`requireAdministrator`を設定するだけの話では？