# ブラウザからパソコンにあるソフトexeファイルを起動

Tags: windows, browser

webアプリからパソコンにあるソフトexeファイルを起動することはできますか？

例えば、オンラインのパワポを使っていて、ローカルのパワポを開くようなことはできますが

パワポではなく、他のアプリを起動したいです。

教えてください。

Comment: 重複候補: [ActiveXを使わずにwebブラウザ上でクライアントのexeを実行する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27343/activex%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%82%8f%e3%81%9a%e3%81%abweb%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a6%e3%82%b6%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%a7%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%82%a2%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%aeexe%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)

Comment: この質問はActiveXを使う等の特定のOSとブラウザの組合せでしか使用できない方法でも構わないのでしょうか？それによって、重複候補の質問と重複しているのか、していないのかが全く異なってくると思います。

Answer (score 1):

可能です。
Javascriptから起動できます。

```
var sh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
sh.Run( "exeファイルのパス",Windowのスタイル);
sh = null;
```

ここらへんを参考にしてください!
https://techacademy.jp/magazine/21620
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 補足ですが、Internet Explorerだけ が可能なやり方です。