# JavaScript から exe ファイル (Outlook) を起動させたい

Tags: javascript, html

はじめまして、現在JavaScriptにてwebページを作成中です。
outlookをボタン押下時に起動させたい(exeを起動するだけで新規メールの作成ではない)のですがうまくいかずに困っています。

以下のコードにてボタンを押すと現状『アクセスが拒否されました。』と出てしまいます。
解決策や別の実行方法があれば教えていただきたく思います。

```
<input type="button" value="sample" onclick=outlookopen('C:¥~~~OUTLOOK.EXE');>

<script la="javascript">

function outlookopen(exePath){
var obj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        obj.Run(exePath);
}
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScriptを使って直接ローカルの実行ファイルを起動する、と言うのはセキュリティ的に問題があるので(悪意のあるサイトにそういうJavaScriptがあると大変ですよね)、たいていのブラウザで動かないようになっていると思います。求められている動作であるかはなんとも言えませんが、そういった動作は「URLスキーム」を利用して実現していることが多いと思います。そちらを調べられてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: `mailto:` ではなぜ駄目なのか、(メールの作成ではないのに) Outlook を起動させて何がしたいのか、辺りの事情をもう少し詳しく書いてみると回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

それはInternetExplorerで、しかも設定をカスタマイズしていないと出来ないはずですが、そうなっていますか？
[How to config IE to make "wscript.shell" work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2138002/9014308)

[Internet Explorer でのスクリプトエラーのトラブルシューティング方法](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/browsers/troubleshoot-script-errors)
[方法 1: アクティブなスクリプト、ActiveX、および Java が Internet Explorer によってブロックされていないことを確認する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/troubleshoot/browsers/troubleshoot-script-errors#method-1-verify-that-active-scripting-activex-and-java-are-not-being-blocked-by-internet-explorer)

[Internet Explorer 11 で ActiveX コントロールを使用する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/17469/windows-internet-explorer-use-activex-controls)

[IEでActiveXを実行](https://qiita.com/tukiyo3/items/fcbda41325024366ce5f)

あと以下のページ近辺でページ左側のリンク一覧にActiveXとかスクリプト関連のオプションの説明があります。
[ActiveX コントロールとプラグインの実行](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::IZ_PolicyRunActiveXControls_5&Language=ja-jp)

---

そうではなくて、URIスキームというのを登録することでActiveXを使わなくても起動できる方法が用意されているようです。
ただし実行する各PCにあらかじめ設定されている必要があります。

4年前に @sayuri さんが回答しています。
[ActiveXを使わずにwebブラウザ上でクライアントのexeを実行する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/27343/26370)

上記記事からのリンク先Microsoftのページ
[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

同じ話題を扱っている外部の記事
[WindowsでURLのプロトコルからアプリを起動する](https://ascii.jp/elem/000/001/211/1211206/)

[プログラム起動　汎用プロトコル](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftedge/forum/all/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0/04736ab4-08f6-4b07-8a3f-5a1064e92cbe)