# ブラウザ上からバッチファイルをキックする方法について

Tags: batch-file

どなたか助けてください。
現在、WebブラウザからPCのローカル上にあるバッチファイルを動かす方法を考えています。
（カスタムURIスキームを使用する）

cmd.exeが起動するようなURIスキームを用意してローカルのバッチファイルを動かそうかと考えているのですがいまいちうまくできません。

どなたか、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\note]
@="url:note protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\note\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\note\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\note\shell\open\command]
@="C:¥¥Windows¥¥System32¥¥cmd.exe
```

Comment: 重複候補: [ActiveXを使わずにwebブラウザ上でクライアントのexeを実行する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/27345)

Comment: 「いまいちうまくいかない」だと何が問題なのかが曖昧なので、もう少し具体的に説明した方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [URLスキーム経由でローカルプログラムを実行する](https://qiita.com/yiaowang/items/8d195ce6dc9edb00e48c)

Comment: タイトルにバッチファイルと明示されていたり、batch-fileタグが付けられていますが、バッチファイル以外であれば起動に成功しているのでしょうか？ バッチファイルにフォーカスする理由がわかりませんでした。また書かれている手順はcmd.exeの起動手順でしかないように見えます。

Comment: あるいはこちらの記事を不完全に覚えていたとかでは？ [WindowsでカスタムURLスキーマを設定し、引数付きで起動できるようにする](https://qiita.com/nagisayuu/items/0c4f3e81652c016fdb64), [Which special variables are available when writing a shell command for a context menu](https://superuser.com/q/136838), [Windows カスタムURLスキームの設定方法（URLからアプリを起動する）](https://inemaru.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/09/08/013958)